# Safari broken, cannot install any extension

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, safari, safari-extensions

My safari refuses to let me install any extension. All installations ended up with a message:

> Safari can't install this extension
>   An error occurred while installing the extension <extension name>.

I have tried at least 2 dozens of unrelated extensions from safari extension page. Restart safari many times. Nothing works!

What can I do? Can I reinstall Safari? If I reinstall Safari, how do i ensure the passwords that are saved by Safari are not lost?

I am using OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 on rMBP 15″ 2014 model.

Comment: I'd start with the basics - Disk Utility, fix permissions & repair drive. Reinstall 10.10.3 from the [combo updater](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1804?viewlocale) Let us know how it goes...

Comment: Done the fix permission and drive repair - there are some permissions fixed and drive is perfectly ok. Also tried to reinstall 10.10.3 from the link but got a page not found error. So far still the same, can't install any extension.

Comment: my bad - I tried to clean the 'nationality' from the link & failed :( try https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1804?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work after I install the OSXUpdCombo10.3.3. Still have the same problem.

Comment: I reinstall OS X from the recovery and it is still not working. I really hate to reinstall the whole MBP from scratch up...

Comment: Finally fixed it by deleting the extension directory in ~/Library/Safari... it is probably due to my Kaspersky safari virtual keyboard extension. Thanks to this link https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5144452

Comment: Glad you got it :)